# Google WorkspaceのAPI（users.list）に関して

Tags: webapi, google-workspace

Google WorkspaceのAPIに関してご質問させてください。
下記、URL情報の「Try this method」をもとにMethod: users.list　IDをKEYにcustomerIdの情報抽出したいのですが以下のエラー内容が出力されている状況です。
テナント開設時に構成したIDは問題なく出力されるので、権限まわりに問題がありそうと考えております。
※KeyにしているIDも特権管理者のRoleは付与しております。
事象が発生している現状で考えうる設定箇所（特に権限まわり）で何か考えられる箇所はないか、アドバイス頂けないでしょうか。

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "forbidden"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

■URL情報
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list?hl=ja&apix_params=%7B%22domain%22%3A%22test01.cloud-sec.work%22%2C%22sortOrder%22%3A%22ASCENDING%22%7D